# How do I know which indexes exist for a field?

Tags: mongodb

I need to use mongo indexes in my code. Therefore I need to know which properties have indexes.

First I fetch the data:

```
const account = await Account.findOne({ _id: accountId })
```

Then I use it, but in this object that is returned to me there doesn't seem to be a way for me to know which properties have indexes.

How do I know which indexes, if any, exist for a field?

Comment: [Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#"Unasking"_the_question). It's not that "properties *are* indices", it's that indices exist for properties. There's no 1:1 correlation. A property may be used in several indices, and an index may index several properties at once.

Comment: @deceze ty for the explanation, I updated my question accordingly

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#indexes…?

Comment: @deceze I can't find such a function on the collection object... however this doc tells about a "listIndexes" function which does the job, ty

Comment: Actually I had found this solution before, but I was hoping there would be a simpler solution than having to manually map the keys returned by listIndexes with the data object returned by a findOne

Comment: Given how the field-index relationship is, the best the API could possibly do is provide some method that lets you ask "is this field part of any index/which indices?" But given that that's a pretty easy question to answer yourself by going through all indices, and that it's not something you typically need to interrogate often programmatically, that API doesn't exist directly.

Comment: ok that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

From the Mongo shell you may try:

```
db.collection('account').getIndexes()
```

This would return all indices which exist in the account collection.  Note that Mongo supports several different types of indices, and also a given index can include one or many fields.

Comment: I need to get these informations from the code, not the shell

Comment: @papillon ...That's a pretty unusual requirement.  Typically you would tune your collection and indices on Mongo directly, before you run your JS code.

Comment: I wish to provide my API with a tool that patches a whole object in 1 line, instead of having to add multiple if-else requirements, lots of which would contain multiple depth levels. I thought I might use a simple findOneAndUpdate, but this does not work if there's a list of objects at some point in the data, which is why I am writing a function that will do the replacement itself.

Comment: actually deceze in the comments above made a decent point to explain why the functionnality I am asking about has simply not been developed yet

Comment: I don't understand why you need to manage your indices programmatically.  Just go directly into Mongo and index.